# Null value multiselect cascading dropdown in MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, multi-select

In MVC I have a **multiselect dropdown list**. On change event i am populating another dropdown, but not able to get multiselect values on the **controller** below is my code.

### View

```
@Html.DropDownList("Country", ViewData["country"] as List<SelectListItem>, new {@multiple="multiple", style = "width:250px", @class = "dropdown1" })
```

### Ajax call

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#Country").change(function () {

        var abc = $("#Country").val();
        alert(abc);


        $("#State").empty();
        $.ajax({               
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("GetStates")', // we are calling json method
            dataType: 'json',
            //data: { id: $("#Country").val() },
            data: { "CountryId": abc },
            cache: false,
            success: function (states) {
                // states contains the JSON formatted list
                // of states passed from the controller
                $.each(states, function (i, state) {

                    alert(state.Value);
                    $("#State").append('<option value="' + state.Value + '">' + state.Text + '</option>');
                }); // here we are adding option for States
            },
            error: function (ex) {
                alert('Failed to retrieve states.' + ex);
            }
        });
        return false;
    })
});
```

### Controller

```
public JsonResult GetStates(string CountryId)
   {
      return null;
   }
```

But i am getting **CountryId** as **NULL** for multi select dropdown case only for normal dropdown i am getting the value.

Is there a work-around for this?

Comment: Your creating a multiple select (which you should be doing using `ListBoxFor()`, not `DropDownListFor()`) which posts an array of values so it needs to be `string[] CountryId` in the method. And do not use the same name for the property your binding to and the `SelectList`

Comment: could you please provide a js fiddle for this? I am unable to make it work. What you said seems to be logical to me. So i would like to see a working example.

Comment: Because its an array your also need to add the `traditional: true,` option, **OR** stringify the data and use `contentType: 'json'`

Comment: Thanks its working now :)

Comment: if i use `traditional: true` with `DropDownListFor()`, even then it is working. Could you please add your solution to the answer section so that I can accept it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your generating a `<select multiple="multiple">` which posts back an array of values, not a single value.

Because you sending an array in the request, you need to add the `traditional: true` ajax option

```
$.ajax({               
    type: 'POST',
    url: '@Url.Action("GetStates")',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { countryId: $("#Country").val() },
    traditional: true,
    ....
```

and then change the controller method to accept the array

```
public JsonResult GetStates(string[] CountryId) // or IEnumerable<string> CountryId
```

Note this works because if a simple array, but in cases where you might be posting back an array of complex objects, then you would need to use the `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'` option and also stringify your data using `JSON.stringify({ someProperty: yourComplexArray });`

Side note; The correct method for creating a `<select multiple>` is to use the `@Html.ListBoxFor()` method, which adds the `multiple="multiple" attribute. In this case, it will work, but in other cases, for example, using`DropDownListFor()`in a loop to create a``, it will fail to bind correctly, so I recommend you use the correct method.